# Using Filter in Java Server Page

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-filters

How I should use filters in JSP?

Which filter is used for filter inputs users?

How I should implement it for filter inputs?

```
@WebFilter("/*")

public class MyFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
        ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    // before pass filter

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    // after pass filter

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter is used to perform a task before or after certain web pages. You define filter in web.xml and also define what URL pattern will go through this filter. Of course, alternatively you can use WebFilter annotation as in your case.For example, you can define a CharsetFilter in web.xml like below:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>net.tangs.business.common.filter.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here I defined a CharsetFilter to be implemented by class CharsetFilter.java (with the full package name) with parameter requestEncoding to be initialized as UTF-8. I also use `<filter-mapping>` and specify that all web pages (/*) will go through this filter.

Now what you need is to create CharsetFilter.java in the package as shown above and implements `java.servlet.Filter` interface.

```
public class CharsetFilter implements Filter {

private String encoding;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");

    if (encoding == null)
        encoding = "UTF-8";
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Respect the client-specified character encoding
    // (see HTTP specification section 3.4.1)
    if (null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
        request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);

    /**
     * Set the default response content type and encoding
     */
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    next.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

}

You have to override 3 methods: init() for initialization, doFilter() for performing actual filtering task and destroy() for any cleanup. Note that in doFilter() method you have access to request and response. For this example, what I did is just setting the request content type and character encoding to UTF-8. Now when you request for any web page in your application, this trunk of code in doFilter() will always be executed first.

Comment: nice explanation, ty bro i was in doubt of how use it.